# jquery unbind and bind on ajax success

Tags: jquery, ajax, bind, unbind

i am creating a slideshow, when i reach on end of lis and click right arrow, ajax should fire and load new list of images. When i reach the end of second list, ajax should fire agaiin. If i click twice fast ajax fires twice and changes global vars that i need, instead of only activating once. I can place hide after else to hide the button so that it can not be pressed twice until ajax success shows the button again. The button is just a div. I do not want to hide it because for a sec it is hidden, and i want it to be visible. If i try to unbind rightNav after else, i can not bind it back again on ajax success.
What could be the problem?

```
rightNav.click( function(){
    if(index <= listLength - 2){
        index = index + 1;
        appendImage(index);
    }
    else {
        rightNav.unbind('click');
        nextUrl = '/GetPhotosCriterians?categoryid=' + pCategoryId + '&styleid=' + pStyleId + '&terms=' + pTerms + '&pos=' + nextPos;
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: nextUrl,
            dataType:"json",
            success: function(data){
                imagesList = data;
                listLength = imagesList.length;
                appendImage(0);
                curentPos = nextPos;
                nextPos = nextPos + imgNumber;
                prevPos = curentPos - imgNumber;
                rightNav.bind('click');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because `rightNav.bind('click');` does not actually bind the `click` event to your function.

The syntax for [`bind`](https://api.jquery.com/bind/) (in your case) is `bind(event, callback)`.

So you could either:

a) Give a name to your function so you can assign it back, such as:

```
var f = function() { if(index <= listLength - 2){ ...
rightNav.click(f);
```

And then you assign it back with:

```
rightNav.bind('click', f);
```

b) Ignore click when ajax is already loading:

```
else {
        //rightNav.unbind('click');

        if (rightNav.loading) {
            return;
        }

        rightNav.loading = true;
        ...
        success: function(data){
            rightNav.loading = false;
        ...
```